# Graficar tiempo en eje x Stacked chart de Highcharts

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

Encontre en los ejemplos de Highcharts este tipo de grafica apilada, pero quisiera en vez de tener etiquetas estaticas en el eje X, tener una linea de tiempo.
Este es el ejemplo:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjRJja

Gracias

Comment: Hola! Agrega el código en la pregunta, si el link deja de existir la pregunta deja de ser valida para los usuarios en el futuro. Puedes utilizar un [Stack Snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3292/qu%c3%a9-es-stack-snippet)